# Use aggregation to match one field of the document with the array size of that same document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I am using nodejs with mongodb and i have below document in my database

```
{
arr: ["abc", "def", "ghi", "jkl"],
ctr: 0
},
{
arr: ["aeiop"],
ctr: 0
}
```

Now i want to write an **aggregation** query if ctr is less than size of array arr then i want to return that document.

Below is the query i wrote

```
areamodel.aggregate(
            { $match : { ctr:{$lt : {$size: "$arr"} } },
            {$sort:{time_posted: -1}},
            function(err, docs) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {

                }
            }
        );
```

But i am not getting anything in response because none of query matches.

Can anyone please tell me in mognodb how to perform aggregation query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider manipulating the [comparison operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/#comparison-operators) within the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline and a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** pipeline to filter documents based on the additional field with the **[`$cmp`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/cmp/#exp._S_cmp)** expression:

```
couponmodel.aggregate([
    {
        "$project": {
            "arr": 1,
            "ctr": 1,
            "time_posted": 1,
            "comparer": { 
                "$cmp": [ "$ctr", { "$size": "$arr" } ]
            }
        }
    },
    { "$match": { "comparer": -1 } }
    { "$sort": { "time_posted": -1 } },
], function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(docs);
    }
});
```

The only drawback with this approach is that you need to project the fields you want as well as creating an additional field that you may not need.

---

Another option which circumvents the above is using a single pipeline with **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#pipe._S_redact)** operator which incorporates the functionality of **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** and **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)** as above and returns all documents which match a specified condition using **[`$$KEEP`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** system variable and discards those that don't match using the **[`$$PRUNE`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** system variable. Keep in mind this operator does a collection scan so the first pipeline option may be optimal given the appropriate indexing techniques:

```
couponmodel.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$eq": [
                        { "$cmp": [ "$ctr", { "$size": "$arr" } ] }, 
                        -1
                    ]
                }, 
                "$$KEEP", 
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    },
    { "$sort": { "time_posted": -1 } },
], function(err, docs) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log(docs);
    }
});
```